# Cassandra datastax | TimeoutException

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax

I have a problem with cassandra I have the following error.
I link a picture

Code syntaxe :

```
 public function find($db_table = null, $db_id = null) {
        $filter = "";
        $return = array();

        $cluster = $this->cluster();
        $session = $cluster->connect($this->keyspace);

        if(isset($db_table)) {
            $filter .= " WHERE db_table like '%".$db_table."%' ";

            if($db_id != null) {
                $filter .= " AND db_id = '".$db_id."' ALLOW FILTERING";
            }
        }

        $query  = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM ".$this->keyspace.".log $filter;");
        $result = $session->executeAsync($query);
        $rows   = $result->get();
```

[Cassandra Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzPUq.jpg)

Comment: Please post the error as text and not as a picture to improve the readability of your question.

Comment: please also post the table structure

Comment: and what version of DSE/Cassandra

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not use "allow filtering" unless you know what you are doing.
2. SELECT * FROM prod.log WHERE db_id = 13913 AND db_table LIKE '%%' product LIMIT 5000 is timing out, as you seem to have a lot of entries in the DB and allow filtering is doing a full table scan.
3. You should adapt the table design to match your queries.

Answer (score 0):

A more detail can be found here.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/php-driver/1.2/api/Cassandra/Cluster/class.Builder/

Using withConnectTimeout may help avoid a TimeoutException

```
$cluster = $this->cluster()->withConnectTimeout(60);
```

you may increase the timeout value Although you update little more by changing values in /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

similar to below --

sudo nano /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml (for editing of cassandra.yaml file)

```
# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 50000
# How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 100000
# How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
# How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 50000
# How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
# that contends with other proposals for the same row
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 10000
# How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
# (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
# we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 600000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 100000

# How long before a node logs slow queries. Select queries that take longer than
# this timeout to execute, will generate an aggregated log message, so that slow queries
# can be identified. Set this value to zero to disable slow query logging.
slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

1. using "LIKE" on cassandra i dont think so :(
2. your query :(  try do something more clean instead use  ".$db_table." do the properly bind  use . ? and then inside your exec(query,['value'])
3. what do your mean ? with SELECT * FROM ".$this->keyspace.".log 
   this is not a query ! if you use this in php, the syntax definitely this is completely wrong.
   you wrote 
   SELECT * FROM keyspace_name.log WHERE table like 'wherever' and id = 'something' :(
   and worse select ALL
   this never gonna happen
4. u use $this for invoke your cluster from where ? did this come from ?

ok i can enumerate 10 different reasons to your code doesn't work, but this is not my goal i want help u so just try something simple.

____ good_____

```
<?

$cluster   = Cassandra::cluster()
               ->withContactPoints('127.0.0.1')
               ->build();
$session   = $cluster->connect("your_k_space");


$table_list = $session->execute("SELECT table_name FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'your_k_space'");


if (in_array($db_table, $table_list)) {
   $options = array('arguments' => [$db_table,$db_id]);
    $result = $session->execute("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE db_id = ?  ALLOW FILTERING",$options);
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) print_r($value);



}else{
    die('table not found');
}
```